# How to disable console options

Tags: .net, console

Is it possible to disable the options dialog box for a .net console application?  Or somehow keep the user from changing the console properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It is not possible.

Actually, it might be possible by acquiring the hWnd of the console window and tinkering with it. But this will certainly cause disasters on other Windows versions / locales. Don't do it.

Anyway, why would you want to do it?